# How to create and print wordcloud in r

Tags: r

Not sure what I'm missing, but when I run this wordcloud example nothing is plotted and x = NULL.

The libraries are all available.

```
abc<-data.frame(X=LETTERS[1:26],x=sample(1:26))

x = wordcloud(abc$X,abc$x,scale = c(5,.5),min.freq = 2,colors = brewer.pal(10,"Paired"))
```

Comment: What library are you using? Works fine for me with the wordcloud library

Comment: Yes, somehow my library was corrupted. Reinstalled and A-OK

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quanteda package. Example based on their documentation https://quanteda.io/reference/textplot_wordcloud.html

```
library(quanteda)
#convert readLines input to a token object
tok <- tokens(unlist(sample.lines))

#convert the token object to a frequency matrix
dfmat1 <- dfm(tok,
              remove = stopwords("english"), #remove stopwords (if wanted)
              remove_punct = TRUE, #remove punctuation (if wanted)
              tolower = T, #(change all to lowercase (if wanted)
              removeNumbers = TRUE) %>%  #remove numbers (if wanted)
   dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 4) #eliminate frequencies lower than 4 (if wanted)



# basic wordcloud
textplot_wordcloud(dfmat1)

# plot in colors with some additional options
textplot_wordcloud(dfmat1, rotation = 0.25, 
                   color = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(10, "RdBu")))

# other display options
col <- sapply(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), function(x) adjustcolor("#1F78B4", x))
textplot_wordcloud(dfmat1, adjust = 0.5, random_order = FALSE, 
                   color = col, rotation = FALSE)
```